# C: How a two-dimensional array works?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

For an two dimensional array,

```
char days[8][10] = { "", "Monday", "Tuesday",
                         "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday",
                         "Saturday", "Sunday" };
```

the model of the array is here:

[image]
<sub>(source: [songjinshan.com](http://songjinshan.com/akabook/_images/array.multichar.png))</sub>

when used in the main function as:

```
printf("%s\n",days[1]);
```

produces `Monday`,while:

```
printf("%s\n",days[1][2]);
```

produces an error. I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: `days[1][2]` is `n` (a `char`)

Comment: Show the code that produced the error.

Comment: how are you using it in the main function?

Comment: printf("%s", days[1][2])
I now understand that I should use a %c instead of the %s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, for an array like

```
  char days[8][10]
```

`days` is an array of 8 elements, each being an array of 10 `char`s.

Put it in other way,

- `days` is the two dimensional array,
- `days[m]` is each of the one dimensional arrays
- `days[m][n]` will be individual elements inside the one-dimensional arrays.

Now, coming to the question,

> *While used in the `main()` function...*

Well, <del>the best guess is</del> as seen in the updated code, you're using it (`days[1]`) as argument to `%s` in `printf()` family of functions.

In that case, `%s` expects a pointer to a null-terminated char array, and `days[1]` (decays to) pointer to the first element of the array `"Monday"`. So that's correct.

On other hand, for `%s` format specifier , `days[1][2]` is a mismatched argument, as it produces a `char` against the expected `char *`. To print `days[1][2]`, you'll need to use a `%c` format specifier.

Comment: Awesome answer! Exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays in C/C++/Java/C# are zero based index, here you have created 2D array or table of characters, when you write days[ 1 ] you are accessing 1st row which is 1D (dimensional) array of characters called **String**, when you write days[ 1 ] [ 2 ] you are accessing a *character* at 2nd row and 3rd column (remember arrays in C are zero based index).

Let me place an edit of your image here to explain the concept.

[image]

**Code Usage**

Now if you want to print the *character* you should write something like,

```
printf("%c\n", days[1][2]);//You are accessing the character in 2nd row (index 1) and 3rd column (index 2) here
```

To print the string you should write,

```
printf("%s\n", days[1]);//You are accessing the 2nd string (array of characters) OR 2nd row in 2D array which is at index 1 (remember '0' based index)
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried,

```
printf("%c\n", days[1][2]);
```

using the `%c` to specify to the `printf` function that you want to print a character.

use `%s` to print string.